# Connect to Web Service without using Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have developed a Payment Gateway Plugin for SagePay South Africa that will be used with the nopCommerce (v3.90) eCommerce platform. The plugin itself work perfectly, however, SagePay requires the plugin to verify a Merchant ID and Service key during the setup and configuration of the plugin. This is done via a Web Service provided by SagePay South Africa.

I am using Visual Studio 2017. The plugin is a web application that extends the functionality of nopCommerce, and is based on ASP.NET MVC 5, wriiten in  C#.

Adding the SagePay Web Service as a "Connected Service" on my development PC is no problem. When I test the plugin the verification process works perfectly. However, when deploying the plugin on the test server the only way I can get the plugin to work, is if I copy the Endpoint Configuration settings (Web.Config) from the plugin folder to the root Web.Config file of the nopCommerce installation.

This is a problem, since we do not want the customers that download the plugin to have to manually edit/modify the root Web.Config file.

So my question is, how would connect to the web service by specifying the Endpoint settings in the Controller code, and in doing so bypass the need for the Plugin to get the Endpoint Configuration settings from the root Web.Config file?

When the plugin is installed on the test server, a web.config file exists in the plugin folder that contains the Endpoint configuration settings for the web service. As I discovered, this does not work since the plugin is looking at the root Web.Config file for these settings.

If I manually add these settings in the root Web.Config, the plugin works perfectly, but as I stated we do not want the users to manually edit the main Web.Config file, for obvious reasons.

This is the Web.Config file in the plugin sub-folder - I need to add this directly in the Controller:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
              <binding name="WSHttpBinding_INIWS_Partner">
                  <security mode="Transport">
                      <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                  </security>
              </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
          <endpoint 
              address="https://ws.sagepay.co.za/NIWS/NIWS_Partner.svc"
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_INIWS_Partner"
              contract="NIWS.INIWS_Partner" 
              name="WSHttpBinding_INIWS_Partner" />
      </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

==================================================

Below id the two methods that require the Web Service above:

```
using Nop.Plugin.Payments.SagePay.NIWS;

protected ServiceInfoList GetServiceInfo(string pServiceID, string pServiceKey)
{

        ServiceInfo serviceInfo = new ServiceInfo
    {
        ServiceId = pServiceID,
        ServiceKey = pServiceKey
    };

    ServiceInfoList serviceInfoList = new ServiceInfoList
    {
        serviceInfo
    };

    return serviceInfoList;
}

protected void ValidateServiceKey(string AccountNumber, string PayNowKey)
{

    //initialise all operations needed
    //---------------------------------------
    ServiceInfoList serviceInfoList = new ServiceInfoList();
    NIWS_PartnerClient client = new NIWS_PartnerClient();
    ValidateServiceKeyRequest validateServiceKeyRequest = new ValidateServiceKeyRequest();
    //---------------------------------------

    string SoftwareVendorKey = "******-****-****-****-************";

    //Populating request to validate
    //---------------------------------------

    //Add account number to MerchantAccount
    validateServiceKeyRequest.MerchantAccount = AccountNumber;

    //Add Vendor key issued by Sage Pay
    validateServiceKeyRequest.SoftwareVendorKey = SoftwareVendorKey;

    //checks if field was populated
    if (PayNowKey != null)
    {
        serviceInfoList = GetServiceInfo("14", PayNowKey);
    }

    //Add service info list to request
    validateServiceKeyRequest.ServiceInfoList = serviceInfoList;

    //---------------------------------------
    //Calling the ValidateServiceKey method validating account number with the service keys added
    var Request = client.ValidateServiceKey(validateServiceKeyRequest);

    //Do a check on the response for Account Status
    //001 = valid
    if (Request.AccountStatus == "001")
    {
        //do something, eg. output if account active
        //then add service info to list to check on each service status
        sageAccountStatus = Request.AccountStatus;

        ServiceInfoResponseList serviceInfoResponseList = new ServiceInfoResponseList();
        serviceInfoResponseList = Request.ServiceInfo;
        foreach (var s in serviceInfoResponseList)
        {
            string service = s.ServiceId;
            switch (service)
            {
                case "14": // Pay Now Service Status
                    sagePayNowStatus = s.ServiceStatus;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {

        sageAccountStatus = Request.AccountStatus;
    }

    client.Close();
}
```

I would like to have the plugin define the settings in the Web.Config file, directly from withing the Controller, therefore, eliminating the need for the Web.Config file.

Comment: use `System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory` ... like `var client = ChannelFactory<IService>.CreateChannel(new WSHttpBinding { Security = new WSHttpSecurity { Mode = SecurityMode.Transport } }, new EndpointAddress(url))`

Comment: Hi Selvin,

Thank you for the quick reply. It seems that you have to have direct access to the service ("IService"} in order to use Channel Factory, if I am to understand the implementation correctly.

The service the plugin connects to is a remote web service. So the way I got it to work so far is to use a Proxy that is generated by using the "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio.

This then exposes the methods on SagePay's server, needed for the plugin to verify the required details. Perhaps I misunderstand you, would this work with Proxie's?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Service Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-service-endpoint-in-code) and [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding) in code. Your generated connected service's constructor should have an overload to accept those arguments, something like this:

```cs
void Foo()
{
    var binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
    var endpoint = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://ws.sagepay.co.za/NIWS/NIWS_Partner.svc");

    var client = new NIWS_PartnerClient(binding, endpoint);

    // ...
}
```